# docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

Tags: docker, ubuntu, wsl-2

I saw similar treads but they are different because I am using WSL2 and docker and GPU aware docker.

I have windows 10 version 2004 (build 20161.1000)
I have installed WSL 2 and have Docker Desktop 2.3.0.3 on my Windows System running.
I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed in WSL 2 too.
I have installed the NVIDIA driver
[image]

The linux version is 4.19.121-microsoft-standard.
The NVIDIA driver version is 455.41 for my Laptop GPU QUADRO M2000M.
Actually I followed all the steps described in https://ubuntu.com/blog/getting-started-with-cuda-on-ubuntu-on-wsl-2 until the step where I have to run "sudo service docker stop" in an Ubuntu terminal.

This results in a message docker: unrecognized service.

I have to restart docker desktop in WIndows 10 in order to get the deamon running.

I test then in the Ubuntu terminal : docker run hello-world ==> this runs fine
Also the command docker run -it ubuntu bash  ==> runs file in the Ubuntu terminal os WSL 2.

BUT when I run :
docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter

then I get the error :  docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

This invoves microsoft,Ubuntu,NVIDIA. I have search the support sites but could not find anything that solves my prblem.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#installing-wip) you have to have the insiders build of windows `Build version 20145 or higher`.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/overview.html) may be this can help you.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was missing toolkit

```
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this strange answer mentioned [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/docker-error-response-from-daemon-could-not-select-device-driver-with-capabilities-gpu/128913/4#post_4) and [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7581#issuecomment-729558589):

```
sudo service docker start
sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
sudo mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
```

This worked for me on WSL (Ubuntu 20.04), so I added it to the `~/.bashrc` script.
**Note, the first part may need to be restarting docker!**

Comment: Thanks! For me, it was a different problem - missing package `nvidia-container-toolkit`